# Is there a Orage package for the current LTS version?

Tags: 22.04, xubuntu, desktop-environments, deb

Is there a Orage deb package for the current Ubuntu 22.04 LTS XFCE DE? everywhere I look it only goes up to 20.04 did anyone manage to install it for 22.04? It is also availablefor latest Debian as well
why doesn't the latest LTS support it?

https://pkgs.org/download/orage

Answer (score 0):

[packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=orage)

```
Pakket orage

    focal (20.04LTS) (x11): Calendar for Xfce Desktop Environment [universe]
    4.12.1-7: amd64 arm64 armhf ppc64el riscv64 s390x
    kinetic (22.10) (xfce): Calendar for Xfce Desktop Environment [universe]
    4.16.0-1: amd64 arm64 armhf ppc64el riscv64 s390x
    lunar (23.04) (xfce): Calendar for Xfce Desktop Environment [universe]
    4.16.0-2: amd64 arm64 armhf ppc64el riscv64 s390x
    mantic (xfce): Calendar for Xfce Desktop Environment [universe]
    4.18.0-1: amd64 arm64 armhf ppc64el riscv64 s390x
```

There is a 23.04 so it is no obsolete.

You will need to ask the maintainer. [Probably here](https://salsa.debian.org/xfce-team/apps/orage)
Maybe it did not work at the time of the release of 22.04.

There are manual instructions on the project page.

Answer (score 0):

Orage is not in the Ubuntu 22.04 default repositories, but it is possible to install the orage package from Ubuntu 22.10 in  Ubuntu 22.04 by running the following commands.

```
cd ~Downloads
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/orage/orage_4.16.0-1_amd64.deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/orage/orage-data_4.16.0-1_all.deb
sudo apt install ./orage-data_4.16.0-1_all.deb ./orage_4.16.0-1_amd64.deb
```

Partial results of the last command:

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libxfce4panel-2.0-4 libxfce4ui-2-0 libxfce4ui-common libxfce4util-bin
  libxfce4util-common libxfce4util7 libxfconf-0-3 xfconf
Suggested packages:
  devhelp sox
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libxfce4panel-2.0-4 libxfce4ui-2-0 libxfce4ui-common libxfce4util-bin
  libxfce4util-common libxfce4util7 libxfconf-0-3 orage orage-data xfconf
0 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: OK will try it thanks hope they will add if in the next LTS version not sure why they skipped on the current one

Comment: I checked it and the default repositories all versions of Ubuntu after 22.04 including the latest development version of Ubuntu contain the orage package.